# mvc 3.0 vulnerability testing tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

Am looking out for list of tools which can do vulnerability testing for application developed on MVC 3.0 and deployed on Azure.

Comment: For Dynamic analysis can I use IBM appscan ????

Comment: Check out https://asafaweb.com/Home/Scans and http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/

Comment: Accept an answer if you found what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Mole](http://themole.nasel.com.ar/) is a nice tool for Sql injection tests via GET, POST and Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Saint, Retina, etc are decent automated tools but cost money.
The question is are you looking for fully automated tools without app knowledge or are you looking for specific tools (browser exploitation framework, SQL ninja, etc) to try specific attack types on your own?

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse,am looking out for automated tools which can scan all top 10 vulnerability listed in OWASP

Comment: I have used HP- Fortify and Appscan for application build on .net 3.5 version------ As per fortify site last version tool support is 3.5 :-( and am pretty not sure is appscan dependent on .net version as it is a dynamic analysis tool

Comment: Saint or retina. But remember you are checking external - .net version support shouldn't matter much as per the owasp top 10. XSS is XSS, SQL Injection is SQL INjection - ie all not dependent on the version. However they all generally have agents that look for unpatched issues based ms patch info on the system (but of course you have to let the agent connect with proper permissions to or ON that system for those checks, which are outside of the owasp top 10. If you are interested in more in depth info for each attack, check out my security series on pluralsight.com

Comment: Thanks,But in static analysis tools there is dependency on version because it perform scan on the code directly eg fortify

Comment: maybe edit your question for a bit more. Theres many things you can check for. Static analysis differs from prod scans, etc. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Basically am looking out tool which scan the vulnerability listed in owasp and cwe/sans

Comment: http://www.nstalker.com/ claims to handle top 10, although any of the major should include most if not all (plus a billion other) checks